# integrating auth0 in office add-in for outlook is causing issues while loading

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

my add-in was working fine initially, but when i tried to integrate authentication using our Autho services it is failing to load.

I tried to implement using dialogApi as demonstrated in [this repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Auth0) 
but it is only supporting from version 1.4, where as I need to support older versions of outlook.

so I had to do it other way instead if relaying on dailogApi. what i did is i configured my source location in my manifest file as below.
[manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFWyF.png)

```
  <SourceLocation
     DefaultValue="https://login.xyz.com/authorize?redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/index.html&amp;client_id=14&amp;scope=network:7:rw"/>
```

added `https://login.xyz.com/` in app domains also.
after changing my source location from `https://localhost:3000/index.html.` my add-in showing below error.

> Apperror- something went wrong and we couldn't start this app.

if I click on try again multiple time authentication is working, but giving me

> Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client

I need help to find if there is any easy way to implement integrating autho with office outlook add-in. I need to support o365, outlook for web, windows and mac.

through my add-in I'm trying to do add one more attendee to list of attendees while creating a meeting. also append some data to meeting body from my api.

.

Comment: Your SourceLocation now contains https://login.xyz.com/.
So this means that login.xyz.com should include Office.js and should define Office.initialize.

And it appears that you are redirecting to https://localhost:3000/ after the user authenticates successfully. So you want to add https://localhost:3000/ to your AppDomains.

There might be a security issue here since you are redirecting from a public server to your localhost. You might want to change from localhost to the name of your localhost box, so something like https://testbox/

Comment: Adding office intialize in login.xyz.com is not an option so is there a way to authenticate using modal pop up? I tried with displaydailog API but it is supported only in office versions after 1.4.

Comment: Since `login.xyz.com` doesn't invoke Office.initialize, then it is just a "random" webpage, so your add-in won't work in all platforms of Outlook. You can try using `window.open`, however, that will open the default browser. If the default browser isn't Internet Explorer, that will break the auth flow since your add-in runs in an Internet Explorer sandbox.

Comment: even if I add office.initialize to login.xyz.com. it will redirect to login.microsoftonline.com for further authentication where i don't have access. i tried with iframe in my app for authentication it is failing to load microsoft login page for security reasons :( .

Comment: Using DisplayDialog is the recommended way for auth and all latest versions of Outlook client support requirement set 1.4 so you should be able to use the Dialog API for Auth.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT but the outlook web version we have is of version less than 1.4 so display dialog is not working.

Comment: Is it a way to upgrade to 1.4? All clients support 1.4 now. https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook